# getView of customized ArrayAdapter isn't called

Tags: android, android-layout

For some reasons getView of my customized ArrayAdapter isn't called and android displays an empty list. I've already inserted cursor.getCount() in my datasource class to make sure my query isn't empty.

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");

    setContentView(R.layout.conference_list_layout);

    Log.d(TAG, "create ConferenceDataSource");
    datasource = new ConferenceDataSource(this);

    Log.d(TAG, "open ConferenceDataSource");
    datasource.open();

    Log.d(TAG, "getAllUpcomingConferences");
    List<Conference> conferences = datasource.getAllUpcomingConferences();

    Log.d(TAG, "set ConferenceArrayAdapter");
    setListAdapter(new ConferenceArrayAdapter(this, conferences));
}
```

Datasource:

```
public List<Conference> getAllUpcomingConferences() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getAllUpcomingConferences called");

    List<Conference> conferences = new ArrayList<Conference>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(
            DatabaseConstants.TABLE_CONFERENCES, 
            fields, 
            DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCE_START + ">" + (Calendar.getInstance()).getTimeInMillis(), 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Conference conference = cursorToConference(cursor);
        conferences.add(conference);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();

    return conferences;
}

private Conference cursorToConference(Cursor cursor) {
    Log.d(TAG, "cursorToConference called");

    Conference conference = new Conference();

    conference.setId(
            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCE_ID)));

    conference.setStart(
            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCE_START)));

    conference.setEnd(
            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCE_END)));

    conference.setTopic(
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCE_TOPIC)));

    conference.setCreator(
            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseConstants.CONFERENCE_CREATOR)));

    return conference;
}
```

ArrayAdapter:

```
public ConferenceArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Conference> conferences) {
    super(context, R.layout.conference_list_item);
    Log.d(TAG, "constructor called");
    this.context = context;
    this.conferences = conferences;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getView called");

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.conference_list_item, parent, false);

    Date conferenceDate = new Date(conferences.get(position).getStart());

    TextView dayOfWeek = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.conference_list_dayofweek);

    dayOfWeek.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("E").format(conferenceDate));

    TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.conference_list_date);

    date.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(conferenceDate));

    TextView time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.conference_list_time);

    time.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(conferences.get(position).getStart())) + 
            new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(conferences.get(position).getEnd())));

    return view;
}
```

conference_list_layout.xml

```
<include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

conference_list_item.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/conference_list_dayofweek"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/conference_list_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/conference_list_dayofweek" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/conference_list_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/conference_list_date" />
```

Could it be, that the error is in the xml file. I'm using several customized ArrayAdapters and they all work fine and look nearly the same. I've read something about using match_parent instead of wrap_content but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your custom adapter(your probably extending `ArrayAdapter`) implement the [`getCount`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getCount%28%29) method and return the list of `Conferences` size:

```
public int getCount() {
   return conferences.size();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot this really worked out ... omg. Why is it working with my other ArrayAdapters without overriding the getCount function?

Comment: @sebbl.sche In the other adapters you probably use other super constructors from the parent class `ArrayAdapter`(that also take a list/array of objects representing the data, from that list the adapter knows what to do in the `getCount` method). In your adapter from the question you use the constructor that takes only the `Context` and a resource id so this adapter doesn't have any data set(so the `getCount` method return 0, the adapter is empty, the getView isn't called). Check the docs for the `ArrayAdapter` class and check the other constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `extends ArrayAdapter` for your array adapter class - otherwise it does not know the method to be called

Comment: I extended it. My class definition looks like this. public class ConferenceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Conference>